# Possible to make a distinct and filter in json?

Tags: java, json, sharepoint

```
{
   "txtContent":"@currentField",
   "style": {
      "display": {
         "operator": "?",
         "operands": [
            {
               "operator": "<=",
               "operands": [
                 "[$Date]",
                  {
                     "operator": "-",
                     "operands": [
                        "@now",
                        259200000
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "none",
            "block"
          ]
      }
   }
}
```

I tried this first, but it´s only useful for 1 column and won´t filter the last entry. The other problem is that the script don´t distinct anything..

PS: I'm using this on an Sharepoint list to format it

Comment: First of all, what is your actual question? And second, please provide a minimal reproducible example of the code you have tried.

Comment: Is there any chance to make a filter for the last entry of the List?

Comment: And i have only this code at top, i don´t work a much with json..i don´t know much about it

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your own attempt and show it to us.